# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, netplan: Setup LACP for two InfiniBand interfaces?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, bonding, netplan, infiniband

I've been asked to setup a bonded InfiniBand interface (LACP) on a Ubuntu server running 20.04 LTS and currently configured with netplan. I've searched the topic, but no real good answer on how to set it up using netplan. Is it even supported? I'm even thinking about just ditching netplan.